# Node TypeScript Chalk Boxen Import Errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've been messing around with a new Node project and I can't get my modules to load correctly and every error points me in a direction that only gets me more errors.

I created a new project, here's the contents of the project's package.json

```json
{
  "name": "module-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/boxen": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/chalk": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.0"
  }
}
```

here's the contents of the default `tsconfig.json` file generated using `tsc init`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                  
    "module": "commonjs",                                
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

Here's my project's TypeScript code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import boxen from 'boxen';
import chalk from 'chalk';

const inputFile = path.join(process.cwd(), 'package.json');
const outputFile = path.join(process.cwd(), 'version.text');

// Write a box to the console
console.log(boxen('This is a box', { padding: 1 }));
// write some red text to the console
console.log(chalk.red('This is red'));
// Read the package.json file
let rawData = fs.readFileSync(inputFile);
// parse the file as JSON
let packageDotJSON = JSON.parse(rawData.toString());
// get the version number
let buildVersion = packageDotJSON.version;
// write the version number to a file
try {
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, buildVersion, 'utf8');
    console.log('File written successfully');
} catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

The application compiles fine, but when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\john\dev\module-test>tsc

C:\Users\john\dev\module-test>node index.js
C:\Users\john\dev\module-test\index.js:9
const boxen_1 = __importDefault(require("boxen"));
                                ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\john\dev\module-test\node_modules\boxen\index.js from C:\Users\john\dev\module-test\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Users\john\dev\module-test\node_modules\boxen\index.js in C:\Users\john\dev\module-test\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\john\dev\module-test\index.js:9:33) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

A google search pointed me to articles like this: https://dev.to/louisgv/typescript-dynamic-module-import-2dln which tell me to do this:

```js
const fsModule = await import('fs');
const fs = fsModule.default;

const pathModule = await import('path');
const path = pathModule.default;

const boxenModule = await import('boxen');
const boxen = boxenModule.default;

const chalkModule = await import('chalk');
const chalk = chalkModule.default;
```

But then two new error messages appear from the TypeScript compiler telling me to add:

```
export {}
```

and change my `tsconfig.json` file to:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "eS2017",                                  
    "module": "ES2022",                                
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

but when I do that, the boxen and chalk imports complain with the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'chalk'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
```

What do I do here to make a simple node app operate with a few internal and external modules loaded? I spent hours yesterday poking and prodding at this respdindg to different errors and trying the different `module` and `target` settings in the project's `tsconfig.json` file.

This is supposed to be easy, right? Or is module loading completely borked here?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I find my answer immediately after posting a question here. I found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c.

I added `"type": "module` to the `package.json` file and uncommented `"moduleResolution": "node",` in the `tsconfig.json` file.